# Why does my angular/express GET work but not POST?

Tags: angularjs, express

Here how my button's set up. The `Updates.getUpdates` is working. `Updates.postAnUpdate` returns 404

```
$scope.postUpdate = function () {
    console.log($scope.update);
    Updates.postAnUpdate($scope.update);

    Updates.getUpdates().then(function (data) {
        $scope.updates = data;

    });
};
```

Here is my lovely services

```
app.factory('Updates', ['$http',
    function ($http) {
        return {
            //Get the current users messages
            getUpdates: function () {
                return $http({
                    url: '/updates/',
                    method: 'get'
                }).then(function (result) {
                    return result.data;
                });
            },

            postAnUpdate: function (update) {
                return $http({
                    url: '/updates/post',
                    method: 'post',
                    data: {
                        update:update,
                    }
                }).then(function (result) {
                    return result.data;
                });
            }
        };


}]);
```

Here's my routes to handle the urls

```
var updates = require('./routes/updates.js');

//Project Updates
app.get('/updates/', updates.getAll);
app.get('/updates/post', updates.newPost);
```

And finally, here's the code that works with a 200 and console text.

```
exports.getAll = function (req, res) {
    console.log('It worked');

}
```

So everything should be working for the post too, but it isn't. I'm just trying to do a console command so I know it works and I'm getting a 404

```
exports.newPost = function (req, res) {
    var db = mongo.db,
        BSON = mongo.BSON,
        newPost = {};


    console.log('This is giving me 404 instead of showing up in terminal');


        newPost.content = req.body.update;
        newPost.author = req.user._id;
        newPost.date = new Date();

        db.collection('updates').save(newPost, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }


            console.log(result);
        });

}
```

Comment: In `postAnUpdate` in `data`, try changing from `update:update` to `'update':update`. If that doesn't work, are you getting a more explained error than just 404?

Comment: did you configured express to allow `POST` method? there should be some line like  `res.header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS' );`

Comment: Thanks for your help! No more detail in the error and adding quotes didn't work. It says 404 in both terminal and browser console.

Comment: Thank you, Kamrul! It's configured in other parts of the app. This is a website that's already working and I'm adding to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks as though this is a simple typographic error.  in your routes:

```
app.get('/updates/', updates.getAll);
app.get('/updates/post', updates.newPost);
```

I think you want

```
app.post('/updates/post', updates.newPost);
```